# State whether the following simultaneous equations have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have searched online and through my textbooks but I'm completely stuck, I'm asked to verify if the following simultaneous equations have unique solutions;

$$y+2z=1\\
-x+y=3\\
2x+3z=2$$

I have the determinant of the matrix, but unsure how to proceed to find what is asked.

Comment: Gaussian elimination? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: The determinant is non-zero, so there exists a unique solution given by $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\-1&1&0\\2&0&3 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: ... and what is the value of the determinant?

Answer (score 5):

Well, once you have this system of equations, its easy to write it in matrix form as you seem to have done:

$$ 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&2\\
-1&1&0\\
2&0&3
\end{bmatrix}}_{A}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3\\
2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We have $\det(A)=0\cdot(1\cdot 3-0\cdot 0)+1\cdot(1\cdot 3)+2(1\cdot 0-2\cdot 1)=3-4=-1.$ So, the determinant is nonsingular. This implies that the matrix represents an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$. So, for any element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, there exists a unique solution. In particular, the matrix equation above admits a unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the second by $2$ and adding to the third we get
$$2y+3z=8$$
$$y+2z=1$$ From here we get $$z=-6,x=10,y=13$$

Answer (score 0):

The general criterion for the existence of a solution of a non-homogeneous linear system is the matrix of the homogeneous part and the augmented matrix have the same rank, i.e. here
$$\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\-1&1&0\\2&0&3\end{bmatrix}=\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2&1\\-1&1&0&3\\2&0&3&2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Furthermore, this rank is the codimension of the (affine) subspace of solutions.

The  homogeneous linear system has maximal rank ($3$) as its determinant is non-zero. Hence the augmented matrix also has rank $3$, and there exists a unique solution.